# Can I permanently deform a mesh with a rig?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature

The title might be a little confusing, so let me clarify. I want to 3D print a model. However, rather than modeling the 3D print in a certain action pose, I would like to model it in the standard T pose and then deform the mesh with a rig and 3D print that deformed mesh. I currently have a completed 3D model than I successfully 3D printed through Shapeways, but when I rigged it and tried to get a different pose it just wan't possible. Shapeways would not recognize the rig deform and the mesh would be in its default stance.

Comment: Have you tried applying the armature deform modifier?

Comment: You know it's possible that I forgot to try that. I'll go test it and let you know. Submit it as an answer though so I can give you a thumbs up and mark it as correct if indeed it is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the *Armature Deform* modifier to the mesh object by clicking the *Apply* button:

[image]

If your object has multiple modifiers, you may want to apply them all. To do this quickly, ensure the correct object is selected and press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Mesh*.

Answer (score 0):

If one isn't using modifiers one can also use

Object > Convert to > Mesh